# Using pointer-to-members for generic access

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that holds a `std::map` with information from players (it's a game, yes). A `std::vector` has to be sorted in decreasing order, in order to render a scoreboard properly (most kills on top).

I've worked out this function which works pretty nicely.
But it's limited to `PlayerScoreBoardInfo::kill` struct member. 
See `feedvector.push_back(it->second.kill);` below.

If there's any way I can replace this in a way I can push_back any value instead of the `::kill` member. Well that's what I am asking, how to do this?

I've tried to make a hack using `#define` but I've failed terribly.

(Believe me...for what I want to know this is a SSEE.)

```
struct PlayerScoreBoardInfo
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int kill, death, suicide;
    unsigned int scorestreak;
    PlayerScoreBoardInfo()
    {
        kill = death = suicide = scorestreak = 0;
        name = "";
    }
    PlayerScoreBoardInfo( std::string strname, int nkill, int ndeath, int nsuicide, int nscorestreak )
    {
        name = strname;
        kill = nkill;
        death = ndeath;
        suicide = nsuicide;
        scorestreak = nscorestreak;
    }
};

class GameArenaManager
{
private:
    GameArenaManager() {}
public:
    std::map<u_long, PlayerScoreBoardInfo> m_Infos;
public:
    static GameArenaManager& GetInstance()
    {
        static GameArenaManager InstanceObj;
        return InstanceObj;
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> inline void SortVecFromMap( std::map<T1,T2>& maptodosort, std::vector<T2>& vectosort )
{
    std::vector<T1> feedvector;
    feedvector.reserve( maptodosort.size() );

    for( std::map<T1,T2>::iterator it = maptodosort.begin(); it != maptodosort.end(); it++ )
        feedvector.push_back(it->second.kill);//Here i'm limiting this function to that struct, how can I 'push_back' ANY value here? instead of 'second.kill' only?

    std::sort(feedvector.begin(), feedvector.end(), std::greater<T1>());

    for( std::vector<T1>::iterator itv = feedvector.begin(); itv != feedvector.end(); itv++ ){
        for( std::map<T1,T2>::iterator itm = maptodosort.begin(); itm != maptodosort.end(); itm++ ){
            if( itm->second.kill == (*itv ) )
                vectosort.push_back( itm->second );
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    GameArenaManager& Manager = GameArenaManager::GetInstance();
    PlayerScoreBoardInfo info[5];
    info[0] = PlayerScoreBoardInfo("Vinicius", 5,4,0,0);
    info[1] = PlayerScoreBoardInfo("Rafael", 9,4,0,0);
    info[2] = PlayerScoreBoardInfo("Marcos", 23,4,0,0);
    info[3] = PlayerScoreBoardInfo("Julius", 1,4,0,0);
    info[4] = PlayerScoreBoardInfo("Ryan", 87,4,0,0);
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++)
        Manager.m_Infos.insert( std::make_pair( i, info[i] ) ); 

    std::vector<PlayerScoreBoardInfo> sortedvec;
    SortVecFromMap( Manager.m_Infos, sortedvec );

    for( std::vector<PlayerScoreBoardInfo>::iterator it = sortedvec.begin(); it != sortedvec.end(); it++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Name: "   <<  (*it).name.c_str()  << " ";
        std::cout << "Kills: "  <<  (*it).kill          << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Works properly, output is:)

```
Name: Ryan Kills: 87
Name: Marcos Kills: 23
Name: Rafael Kills: 9
Name: Vinicius Kills: 5
Name: Julius Kills: 1
```

I believe the question title is wrong, I don't know how to ask this properly so feel free to edit it. (Please note I'm not very experienced with C++)

Comment: Upvoting for multiple 'green flags' (as opposite to red flags) in the code created by a novice (as stated by OP).

Comment: Just an aside: you can provide default values to your ctors, so you won't need a default ctor. You should also look up [initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). Nice code for a beginner. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For someone who claim to be 'not very experienced in C++' you provide a very nice code ;)

If I understood the question, what you need is a pointer-to-member. Here is a an example:

```
template <...> inline void SortVecFromMap(std::map<T1,T2>& maptodosort, std::vector<T2>& vectosort, unsigned int std::map<T1, T2>::mapped_type::* member )
{
    ...
    feedvector.push_back(it->second.*member);
    ...
}
```

Here is how you can call it:

```
SortVerFromMap(my_map, my_vec, &PlayerScoreboardInfo::death);
```

Comment: uhm, not working really, is this C++ 11? i'm using MS visual studio 2003..error C2751: 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc>::value_type' : the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified

Comment: Should be C++98. Let me compile it, may be I made a typo. Where exactly do you see the error, and what is the error?

Comment: You did not actually use `template <...>`, I hope? This was just to shorten the line. The template definition stays the same as in your original code.

Comment: I've found the typo in the code, fixed. Now it compiles correctly in my env.

Comment: Pastbin is closed for me. How about coliru? Even better - here is the link to compiled code:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42e0cf5f82c980f8 (your code complete).

Comment: My copy-paste ate the `::` after `unsigned int std::map<T1, T2>::mapped_type` in function definition. Sorry about it! Should be good now. Please note, if you are to compile your code in gcc, you'd have to alter it a bit - add a `typename` in a couple of places (you can look at my example to see where). VS2003 will not need this, but it is a requirement of C++ standard, so following this will do you good (unless VS2003 will choke on it, which is possible)

Comment: Still not working, when you've got free time could you provide a compileable working version of it? I should accept your answer then. Thank you!

Comment: @ViniyoShouta, I did! Look at the link I've posted above yours. It has a full code, compiled and ran.

Comment: Ah it doesn't work on MSVS2003 tho, `error C2653: 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc>::mapped_type' : is not a class or namespace name`

Comment: If you want to do it in another way feel free, but don't worry if you don't want to, this answer is just a 'go study pointer to members' for myself. Thankyou

Comment: How about replacing `unsigned int std::map<T1, T2>::mapped_type::* member` with `unsigned int T2::* member`? Like here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afa56053544953c9